# Dynamic loading of data into ViewPager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

There is an Activity with a ViewPager and a tied TabLayot. Depending on the presence / absence of data, fragments are formed for the display. One of the fragments is inherited from ListFragment. To fill a sheet, you need to take data from a separate query, so it was advisable to load them only if the user goes to this fragment. How to implement data loading when selecting a fragment to show, not when creating?

Comment: try mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1); after finding the object of view pager

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method setUserVisibleHint, this method is called only when fragment is visible to user..

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        loadData();
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For a one-time run, added a check for missing data

`if (isVisibleToUser && getListView().getCount() <= 0) {`